# Django Forms: MultipleSelect with choices from another model (Foreign Key)

Tags: django, forms, multiple-select

I'm trying to create a form where the user can select multiple technician. When I add the line `technician = forms.SelectMultiple(label='Technicians Involved')` to my **forms.py** I get a big blank box with no data. How can I populate that box with the technicians from the User model?

**models.py**

```
class Incident(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user')
    technician = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='technician')
    capa = models.CharField('capa number', max_length=9)
```

**forms.py**

```
class IncidentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    ###################### TRYING! ################################
    technician = forms.SelectMultiple(label='Technicians Involved')
    ###############################################################

    class Meta:
        model = Incident
        fields = [  'user_id',
                    'technician',
                    'capa',
                ]
```

**views.py**

```
def report_incident(request):

    template = "report.html"

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = IncidentForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            # Auto capturing logged in user
            incident = form.save(False)
            incident.user_id = request.user
            incident.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/incidents/')
    else:
        form = IncidentForm() #an unbound form

        return render(request, template, {'form': form})
```

************** **UPDATE WITH CORRECTIONS I MADE BELOW** *********************

**models.py**

```
class Incident(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user')
    technician = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='technician')
    capa = models.CharField('capa number', max_length=9)
```

**forms.py**

```
class IncidentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    technician = forms.SelectMultiple()

    class Meta:
        model = Incident
        fields = [  'user_id',
                    'technician',
                    'capa',
                ]
```

**views.py**
No changes

**admin.py** 
Changes made to view multiple technicians per incident in the admin interface.

```
class IncidentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('id',
                        'user_id',
                        'capa',
                        'get_technicians'
                        )

       def get_technicians(self):
            return "\n".join([t.technicians for t in obj.technician.all()])
```

Comment: You want to select multiple Technicians for an Incident but each Incident object can only have one technician (while a Technician can have multiple Incidents). Or am I getting something wrong here?

Comment: Correct. Where am I limiting myself to where and Incident object can only have one technician?

Comment: you've limited it by using a foreign key - you need a many to many

Comment: I think he wants a many to many... otherwise you make a new problem that a user can only have one incident

Comment: @Anentropic yep you're right!

Comment: Thanks! I will give Many to Many a read over.

Answer (score 4):

Try this out

```
class IncidentForm(forms.ModelForm):
   technician = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), queryset=User.objects.all())

     class Meta:
        model = Incident
        fields = [
                'technician',
                'capa',
               ]
```

Comment: No dice. I took the `u` out of `SelectMultiple` and replaced the comma with an open parenthesis.

Comment: `'User' object is not iterable`. I'm going to use Many to Many in my models.py

Comment: I edited my answer to work with your revision, and found that this works much nicer because what you have above in your forms.py is just using the default field from your model which forms.ModelForm ends up supplying. SelectMultiple is a widget, not a form field. Sorry for my first answer I had before it was not calculated and a waste of your time.

Comment: this looks about right now... though you should include all the fields on the form because they're all required at the model level currently