# implementing checkboxes with multiple select in django admin and modelform?

Tags: django-forms, django-views

i'm fairly new to django, so couldn't find a way to implement the checkboxes with multiple select in to my custom modelforms and django admin. tried the django docs but still couldnt find solution?[the image is my project form wherein the technologies field should have a checkbox with multiple select.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFHEa.jpg)
TIA

views.py

```
class ProjectCreate(CreateView):
model = Project
fields = ['projectid', 'title', 'description', 'startdate', 'enddate', 'cost', 'Project_type',
          'employeeid', 'technologies', 'clientid', 'document']


class ProjectUpdate(UpdateView):
model = Project
fields = ['projectid', 'title', 'description', 'startdate', 'enddate', 'cost', 'Project_type',
          'employeeid', 'technologies', 'clientid']
```

form-template.py

```
{% for fields in form %}
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <span class="text-danger small">{{ fields.errors }}</span>

    </div>
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">{{ fields.label_tag }}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">{{ fields }}</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can implement is using [django-multiselectfield](https://pypi.org/project/django-multiselectfield/)

1. First install `django-multiselectfield`.

> **`pip install django-multiselectfield`**

2. In `Models.py`, we need to import `multiselectfield` then use `MultiSelectField` as modal field & pass required arguments.

   ```
   from django.db import models
   from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField

   MY_CHOICES = ((1, 'Value1'),
                 (2, 'Value2'),
                 (3, 'Value3'),
                 (4, 'Value4'),
                 (5, 'Value5'))

   #choices can be a list also

   class MyModel(models.Model):

       #....

       my_field = MultiSelectField(choices=MY_CHOICES,
                            max_choices=3,
                            max_length=3)
   ```

---

Now in admin panel when you open `MyModel form` you will see 5 check boxes out of which you can only select a maximum of 3 as defined `max_choices=3`

If you are rendering `modelform` using templates then you only need to specify the fields in `Forms.py`.

**If you're getting dropdown data from another table then refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31970931/django-forms-multipleselect-with-choices-from-another-model-foreign-key)**